# How to convert redux-thunk action that returns promise to use async/await?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to wire redux-thunk into Next.js and it works fine if my thunk returns a promise.  How do I convert that to use async/await?  I took a look at this article ([how to async/await redux-thunk actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930443/how-to-async-await-redux-thunk-actions)) but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.

My `getInitialProps` in my index.js is

```
static  getInitialProps(props) {
    const {store, isServer} = props.ctx;
    if (!store.getState().placeholderData) {
      return store.dispatch(loadData());
    }
```

and currently my action that handles loading the data is

```
export const loadData = () => (dispatch) => {
  return isoFetch(homeES_endpoint)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => dispatch(loadDataSuccess(data)))
      .catch(err => console.error('error loading data', err.toString()));
}
```

How might I convert loadData to use async/await?  I've tried

```
export const loadData =  () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await isoFetch(homeES_endpoint);
    const data = await res.json();
    dispatch(loadDataSuccess(data));
  } catch(error) {
    //dispatch({ type: LOGIN_ERROR, error });
    console.error('error loading data',error.toString())

  }
}
```

but the main `getInitialProps` in '_app.js' doesn't wait for it.

Comment: I can't say if this is the only problem because the question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , but the only difference is that dispatch isn't awaited. Also, it's `err` in one place and `error` in another, is it a typo?

Answer (score 6):

It's not specific to redux-thunk. `async..await` is syntactic sugar for promises. Once you know how exactly it works, it can be applied to any situation. `await` is a substitute for `.then(...)`. `try..catch` is a substitute for `catch(...)`:

```
export const loadData = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await isoFetch(homeES_endpoint);
    const data = await res.json();
    const result = await dispatch(loadDataSuccess(data));
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('error loading data', err.toString()));
  }
}
```

The difference is that `dispatch(...)` is returned from `then` and thus a proper translation needs it to be `await`ed. A known pitfall of `async..await` is that if a promise is returned with `return dispatch(...`), it won't be handled with `try..catch`.

Comment: Thanks.  So `dispatch(loadDataSuccess(data))` returns a promise itself, even if loadDataSuccess is a synchronous action?

Comment: I just updated the answer. Actually, this may depend on middlewares that are in use in your case. `dispatch(loadDataSuccess(data))` *can* return a promise, and in this case `await` is necessary to cover this case. If `loadDataSuccess`  synchronous and no other middlewares, await won't affect anything.