# UseEffect async actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

In my useEffect hook i have a few API requests, like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(action1());
    dispatch(action2());
    dispatch(action3());
}, []);
```

How can i use 'loading' parameter inside hook using async/await function to have loading as true before dispatching first request, and as false after dispatching last request.
Like:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    dispatch(action1());
    dispatch(action2());
    dispatch(action3());
    setLoading(false);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    setLoading(true);
    await dispatch(action1());
    await dispatch(action2());
    await dispatch(action3());
    setLoading(false);
  }
  fetchData()
}, []);
```

Read more about `useEffect` and `async`: [React Hook Warnings for async function in useEffect: useEffect function must return a cleanup function or nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret)

Comment: `awiat dispatch` isn't actually waiting to action finish it process at the reducer

Comment: @HagaiHarari You have to configure your dispatcher to do so:  You can just wrap everything into an promise. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930443/how-to-async-await-redux-thunk-actions

Answer (score 0):

I always create a custom hook and use that for API call and redux dispatch. have a look this might help.

```
const useAction = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = async (params) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      // do something
      // await call api
      dispatch(action1());
      dispatch(action2());
      dispatch(action3());
    } catch (error) {
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return { fetchData, loading };
};

// Component
const { fetchData, loading } = useAction();
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData(params);
}, []);
```